# Insert label values in divs with a class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to insert all label values in my p class `rowSvar`.  I tried this script undereath but I get both answers in my p tag. How do I only get each answer?

```
<div class = "rows">
 <div class = "row" id = "rowOne">
   <p>Förväntas deltagarna arbeta kreativt?</p>
   <p class = "rowSvar"></p>
   <p></p>
   <p></p>
 </div>
 <div class = "row" id = "rowTwo">
   <p>Vad är huvudmålet med mötet?</p>
   <p class = "rowSvar"></p>
   <p></p>
   <p></p>
 </div>
```

```
var labels = $('#from :checked').map(function() {
return $(this).closest('label').text();
}).get();

  labels.forEach(function(e) {  
    $('.rowSvar').append(e);
  });
```

Comment: what is "labels"?

Comment: select the class only with id `rowone` @Jacktheman

Comment: well if it's a string, it shouldn't have the property `forEach`, `forEach` is for arrays only.
You can `.split(' ')` label with spaces to turn it into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify which `.rowSvar` should receive which answer.
`$('.rowSvar')` selects multiple elements, each element should get the appropriate answer, I'm assuming your `labels` are ordered exactly as your `.rowSvar`s are.

```js
labels.forEach(function(e, index) {  
  $('.rowSvar')[index].append(e);
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it was the the index part i was missing!